# Flutter Page View Flip Transition

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want this animation in flutter , can anyone help me with this animation code for page view

[!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CoXb.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CoXb.jpg)

Animation Video - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vDIsLa2d3SleuCaUWeWwLYsS1eRoE0iN/view?usp=sharing

I have tried many tranform effect but did'nt get the same.
Please help me in this regards to get the correct animation as shown in this video .